# Raspberry Pi Zero emulate mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, emulation, hid, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm looking for a way to use my Raspberry Pi Zero as a HID mouse.

Goal: I put the Pi in my computer and it automatically starts to move the mouse quickly from top to bottom and from bottom to top.

So in principle like the USB Rubber Ducky, but as a mouse HID

What options do I have?

I have only found this tutorial, but it isnt for mouse
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/

I hope you can help me
Thank you

Comment: if you found a solution for that. it would be great to share with us , and add an Answer for it :D

Comment: Please refer to Tiny Pilot, although it uses Raspi4 but I think the Gadget Service is similar. https://github.com/mtlynch/tinypilot. Also for Mouse HID report, please refer to https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf page 61.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [page https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=234495](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=234495), it has a solution that allows you to send mouse movements from the RPi to the attached machine.
The difference between emulating a mouse and a keyboard is that for the mouse you need to set the *report_length* to 3 and the bytes of the *Report Descriptor* are different.